# Openshift wont run nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift

I am attempting to run my chat program using socket.io on my openshift server, but whenever i try to reload the link it gives me, it just keeps on saying: "503 service error". I have setup my repository correct and entered my ssh key into openshift using the rhc client, but to no avail, I am using the port 3000 and I have also tried the port 80 but neither of them work.

Here is my code for the server and my package.json:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    http = require("http").Server(app),
    io = require("socket.io")(http),
         require("./index.js");

app.use(express.static("static"));

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log("a user connnected");
    socket.on("disconnect", function() {
        console.log("user disconnected");
    });

    socket.on("chat message", function(msg) {
        console.log("message " + msg);
        io.emit("chat message", {m: msg.m, u: msg.u});
    });
});


var port;

if(process.argv[2]) {port = process.argv[2]} else {port = 3000}

http.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("chat listening on port " + port + ".");
});
```

And my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ChatterBox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": ".",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
  "express": "^4.12.3",
  "socket.io": "^1.3.5"
},
  "devDependencies": {},
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"repository": {
 "type": "git",
 "url": "https://github.com/OrganTrouble/ChatterBox.git"
},
 "author": "Jesse Davda",
 "license": "ISC",
 "bugs": {
"url": "https://github.com/OrganTrouble/ChatterBox/issues"
},
"scripts" {
 "start": "node $relative_path_from_repo_dir/index.js"
},
"homepage": "https://github.com/OrganTrouble/ChatterBox"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the `OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT` environment variable (along with example usage at the bottom of the page): https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-js-environment-variables.html

See also: https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-js-project-structure.html#server.js

Answer (score 0):

use $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR instead of $relative_path_from_repo_dir